# Htaccess language redirect for joomla page

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with 6 languages - i use /en and /de or /it for language codes in the url.
I want to redirect one langauge (IT) to another domain (external link - just forward the user to the italian website). I think .htaccess is the right way to do this.

.htaccess is still too complex for me.

user should only be redirected when trying to access the italian language on the site, so basically once he accesses some url that has the /it/ language tag.

can anyone help out with some .htaccess magic?

I tried to modify the following code that i found but i don't understand it enough yet... doesn't work yet...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(it.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/it/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Never use `.htaccess` style configurations if you have access to the real server configuration! It is much more expensive (performance goes down), much harder do debug and support and often requires a more complex setup compared to implementing the same rules in the real server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^it/(.*)$ http://another-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Requested URL: `http://old-domain.com/it/hello`

Will redirect to: `http://another-domain.com/hello`